Importing XML in QGIS
I tried to import a .xml file into QGIS (3.32.2-Lima) with the LandXML plugin and got this error:

Problem importing xml 'name'.

So I guess the .xml file is not compatible with this plugin.
The second try was by going to Layer > add vector layer > File and uploading the .xml file, only to get this error:

.xml is not a valid or recognised data source.

The last try was by importing the .xml file as a raster file by going to Layer > Add Raster Layer > File, only to get this error again:

.xml is not a valid or recognised data source.

Startline of the .xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

How can I import this XML metadata into QGIS? Or is there a workaround, if not possible to directly import it?

what sort of data is in your XML file? they can be used to store pretty much anything but QGis is only capable of reading a small subset of everything

Can you please provide a sample of your data?

The plugin is designed to work with LandXml files generated by the Land Information New Zealand Landonline application - it may not support LandXml from other sources    Is the XML file LandXML  created through that application, if not how was it generated?
